# Nested Generic TS - set the args as 'and' and not 'or'

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I am trying to create Human function hooks in my project
and I used generic to decide and to hold the hooks for each available function
I don't want to set all the potential functions, only when we add the hook I want to declare it if it has not yet been declared
But for some reason the TS is multiplied by the args to be 'and' and not 'or' in hooks change
To make checking it easier, I set up a TS playground

I assume it's my lack of knowledge of typescript
will appreciate any help

```
interface HumanFunctionTypeMap {
    eat: {
        name: string;
        diet: boolean;
        vegan: boolean;
    };

    drink: Array<{
        diet: boolean;
        regular: boolean;
        soda: boolean;
    }>;

    sleep: {
        dream: boolean;
        snooze: boolean;
    };
}

type HumanHookName = keyof HumanFunctionTypeMap;

type HumanHook = {
    [K in HumanHookName]?: {
        hooks: Array<(args: HumanFunctionTypeMap[K]) => void>;
        handler: (args: HumanFunctionTypeMap[K]) => void;
    };
};

interface RegisterHumanHook {
    <K extends HumanHookName>(name: K, hook: (args: HumanFunctionTypeMap[K]) => void): void;
}

const humanHooks: HumanHook = {};

export const registerHumanHook: RegisterHumanHook = (name, hook) => {
    if (!humanHooks[name]) {

        humanHooks[name] = {
            hooks: [],
            handler: args => {
                humanHooks[name]?.hooks.forEach(hook => hook(args));
            }
        };

    }

    humanHooks[name]?.hooks?.push(hook);
};
```

```
Type '{ hooks: never[]; handler: (args: HumanFunctionTypeMap[K]) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'HumanHook[K]'.
  Type '{ hooks: never[]; handler: (args: HumanFunctionTypeMap[K]) => void; }' is not assignable to type '{ hooks: ((args: { name: string; diet: boolean; vegan: boolean; }) => void)[]; handler: (args: { name: string; diet: boolean; vegan: boolean; }) => void; } & { hooks: ((args: { diet: boolean; regular: boolean; soda: boolean; }[]) => void)[]; handler: (args: { ...; }[]) => void; } & { ...; }'.
    Type '{ hooks: never[]; handler: (args: HumanFunctionTypeMap[K]) => void; }' is not assignable to type '{ hooks: ((args: { name: string; diet: boolean; vegan: boolean; }) => void)[]; handler: (args: { name: string; diet: boolean; vegan: boolean; }) => void; }'.
      Types of property 'handler' are incompatible.
        Type '(args: HumanFunctionTypeMap[K]) => void' is not assignable to type '(args: { name: string; diet: boolean; vegan: boolean; }) => void'.
          Types of parameters 'args' and 'args' are incompatible.
            Type '{ name: string; diet: boolean; vegan: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'HumanFunctionTypeMap[K]'.
              Type '{ name: string; diet: boolean; vegan: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; diet: boolean; vegan: boolean; } & { diet: boolean; regular: boolean; soda: boolean; }[] & { dream: boolean; snooze: boolean; }'.
                Type '{ name: string; diet: boolean; vegan: boolean; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ diet: boolean; regular: boolean; soda: boolean; }[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

I have tried to set the `humanHooks[name as HumanHookName]` but then I loosing the benfits of the TS, since the `args => args:any` instead of the type we used

I have tried to change the sturcture but got back to the same issue

Comment: This is very close to the approach as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) for dealing with this sort of correlated typing, but the one missing bit seems to be that the compiler is losing track of the mapping from `HumanHook`. If I change it to the form of a distributive object type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NB1bzw) then it works. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it sorts out my code, Thanks :)
but why do I need to specify the type of `registerHumanHook` again?
and what is meaning of `K extends HumanHookName = HumanHookName`

Comment: You don't *need to*, but it makes `K` accessible. If you don't, then `K` is anonymous and you need `typeof name` instead. I'll do that in my answer, actually. ... `K extends HumanHookName = HumanHookName` is declaring a type parameter constrained to `HumanHookName` which defaults to `HumanHookName`.  So `HumanHook` without a type argument behaves like `HumanHook<HumanHookName>` which is the same as your original version.

Answer (score 1):

This is very close to the approach as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) to handle correlated typings.

Note that there really isn't anything wrong with your types, it's just that TypeScript can't follow the logic.  The solution involves refactoring to use essentially equivalent types, but ones whose *forms* are understandable.

---

The only difference I see is that your `HumanHook` type is a single object type, and therefore `HumanHook[K]` is just a plain indexed access type, but TypeScript apparently wants to use a *distributive object type* (as coined in ms/TS#47109) instead.  If `K` is a single key then there's no difference, but in the presence of [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), the compiler is concerned about cross-correlations and in order to be safe it demands an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).  You can read [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) for why this is the case, but we want to avoid that.

So instead of `{[P in HumanHookName]?: F<P>}[K]` (which is `HumanHook[K]` given your definition, and using `F<>` as shorthand), we need to use `{[P in K]?: F<P>}[K]` to make it a distributive object type.  We can get this by rewriting your `HumanHook` to take a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument `K` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `HumanHookName`.  And we can even give it [the default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `HumanHookName` so that when you write `HumanHook` with no generic, it is equivalent to your old version.  Like this:

```
type HumanHook<K extends HumanHookName = HumanHookName> = {
  [P in K]?: {
    hooks: Array<(args: HumanFunctionTypeMap[P]) => void>;
    handler: (args: HumanFunctionTypeMap[P]) => void;
  };
};
```

So now `HumanHook<K>` looks a lot like `Pick<HumanHook, K>` (using [the `Pick` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)) except that the compiler understands the former and not the latter in what's to follow:

```
const humanHooks: HumanHook = {};

export const registerHumanHook: RegisterHumanHook = (name, hook) => {
  const h: HumanHook<typeof name> = humanHooks;
  // const h: HumanHook<K>
  if (!h[name]) {
    h[name] = {
      hooks: [],
      handler: args => {
        h[name]?.hooks.forEach(hook => hook(args));
      }
    };
  }
  h[name]?.hooks?.push(hook);
};
```

Instead of using `humanHooks` of type `HumanHook`, we use `h` of type `HumanHook<K>` (except that your implementation uses [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) of its parameters so `K` is anonymous.  We can use `typeof name` to recover it, so the type is `HumanHook<typeof K>`.  Or we can just forget contextual typing and give your implementation a fully annotated call signature.  Either way).

Note that for every `K`, `HumanHook<K>` is a supertype of `HumanHook`, so it's safe to widen.  That is, `const h: HumanHook<typeof name> = humanHooks;` is allowed.  After this, the type of `h[name]` is seen as `HumanHook<K>[K]`, and this is a distributive object type equivalent to `F<K> | undefined`.  And now everything works as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIFcC2cQDF0gJjAD2IAKgJ4AOEAsnNcgN4BQyyEcYAXC+x2Qg4mCHwDOYKKADmAbgEcAJsAi9kAIxIkANlxALByAG4QZOPlt37DyAL4KBS6SADWfAIJQocSgB42IxU1S209HFsOKDN0HTgoUOsIxWRxEiU4RPCDATsAPkcOcT0Iaj5AwWcuTCybFPEQbQAvMU0wuo4HVjtWVjAaFAxsEFRtVwA5ERQAXmRXCEoSGDQsHHxCYjIqWgZqR37aFeHRklc-AGlOAA9IECVxI5wTiankWaGnscnRPLf+DgA2gAFZCgZDnAC6AH5yikABZjcSeby+PwACniMiRjzwBCIpAoA12wIhAEo3r9jCRgEoCvCcEo9AlkBioFi+B9cRsCdt6IwSeTppTqUpbF0uqxQJBYIgUAAlMzASTQTnPf7IC7XW73HHPb4QPJo4SiPjnAA0yARpz4rPZOPW+K2RP5kMFwpppL4VJpCh6rAQZEkltWI0RHJDatmzC6ECu1BIUDAyADICD0RkSulqrGfAVGeVUGzpz+RqmFqtrjd6pTQbh4eOYz8BwgSyEU1+szhEcRtgA9L3k4Gk3XdY3znkBMBlmiAIRwgHGiBk9UceeLiF-CpGCvYgEQs0pVcMpl8TEPIUroyWhdTaEAOh3d5gCYAoog4WiKxTLWNbeJSaSkSCD0RhdJ0AhrreUIPoi0HUOg4gfhWgHdHIQA)